# Is ice forming on the side of the house normal or problem?

Tags: vinyl-siding

I noticed ice forming on the side of my house.

Is this likely a problem or just normal winter thing?

[image]

Comment: A bit odd, since it requires dripping water.  Not usually where you see water dripping.  Possible a roof leak/ice dam problem.

Comment: Indeed, big question is where the water came from. On the plus side, your insulation must be reasonably good.

Comment: Not shown, but wind and icicles on the edge might cause it, but would need a high wind, that close to the top.

Comment: Surely you noticed it's alignment with the end laps. Maybe those are drip edges that shed the water instead of allowing it to run along the bottom edges further. It would be driven to run by wind or gravity. I would look upstream of the drips for the water source. Alternatively, I suppose it could be coming from inside the wall, but that's relatively unlikely.

Comment: I just realized that the wind would have pushed the drips of water further on the lower surface. That leaves a sloped wall plus gravity, but those drops also would have moved horizontally after dripping.